# Is it appropriate to substitute Kahlua in lieu of Patron XO Cafe?

Tags: cocktails, substitutions

I have a cocktail recipe that calls for Patron XO Cafe. I try to avoid buying bottles of super speciality liquors if I don't anticipate I'll use them frequently. I do have Kahlua on hand which I know is rum based vs tequila based but since they are both coffee liquors I wondered if that would be an appropriate swap?

Comment: That might depend on what else is in the cocktail, wouldn't it?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax for this particular cocktail the other ingredients are vodka, espresso, and simple syrup to be shaken with ice and served in a martini glass. The recipe calls for 1 oz Vodka, 1 oz espresso 1/3 oz of the Patron XO Cafe, and 1/3 oz of simple syrup.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really have a solution, I just wanted the recipe. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can definitely substitute Patron XO Cafe with Kahlua concerning the coffee flavor for your drink.

But...

1. You'll lack a Tequila taste
2. Kahlua has a lower ABV

You can try to compensate this by adding a small amount of tequila, if you have a regular one available. So, instead of buying Patron XO Cafe, use Kahlua and a small amount of simple Tequila.

Comment: that's a great idea. I would never have thought to add a little tequila. This is a really helpful tip in general for substitutions.